# How to change Maximize, Minimize and Close buttons of some apps in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, themes, 22.04, gtk, window-buttons

I am using the Whitesur GTK theme. Everything works fine, but some applications, like GNOME Planner, have their own minimize, maximize and close buttons, as shown in the following screenshot.

[image: two applications with different minimize, maximize and close buttons]

How can I replace them with Whitesur ones?

Comment: You will need to edit source code or check with the developer. Are you effectively using Ubuntu 14.04 as you suggest with your tag?